# How can I record SQLAlchemy generated SQL and query execution times?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to store the SQL queries generated by SQLAlchemy, and how long each one takes to run. I'm using an event listener to store the SQL:

```
statements = []

@listens_for(DBSession.get_bind(), "before_cursor_execute", named=True)
def before_cursor_execute(**kw):
    statements.append(kw['statement'])
```

Can I use the same event listener somehow to store execution time, or should I be using something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `before_cursor_execute` to record the *start time* of your query, then calculate the difference in `after_cursor_execute`, something like this:

```
@event.listens_for(engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def _record_query_start(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
    conn.info["query_start"] = datetime.now()

@event.listens_for(engine, "after_cursor_execute")
def _calculate_query_run_time(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
    print("this query took {}".format(datetime.now() - conn.info["query_start"]))
```

Comment: @technazi Anywhere you have access to `engine`.